# unable to send email with phpmailer with gmail account

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I readly feel confused why i test many many example and correct example to send email with php mailer with gmail account but it did not work,here is the error

```
> 2015-04-21 07:06:50   CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.ariarules.com
 2015-04-21 07:06:50    CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
 2015-04-21 07:06:50    CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.ariarules.com
 2015-04-21 07:06:50    CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
 2015-04-21 07:06:50    CLIENT -> SERVER:
 2015-04-21 07:06:52    SMTP ERROR: Username command failed:   
 535          Incorrect authentication data
 2015-04-21 07:06:52    SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
 2015-04-21 07:06:52    CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
 2015-04-21 07:06:52    SMTP connect() failed.
 Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

and my code

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "googleaccount@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "pass";
$mail->SetFrom("user@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("user@gmail.com");
if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

at end it's better to know i test tls & ssl with port 465 & 587 but....

Comment: does your password has Special characters?

Comment: yes sth lke this Stach1234

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949824/smtp-error-could-not-authenticate-in-phpmailer

Comment: i vist all those pages but ...
it isnot logical,i said i test all these code and methods but it doesnot have any changes

Comment: Are your username and set from different? And btw is your username correct? It looks like your username doesn't exist. And if you use a from different from the user it may be considered as spam

Comment: i give you real username & passwod:username:Hamed2Beyranvand@gmail.com
password:hamed1371
i'm weating for you answer,thanks friend

Comment: the same error again,i think there is no problem with my codes,but what happend except the codes????!!!

Comment: try $mail->isHTML(true);

Comment: remove $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';and  also uncoment php_openssl.dll in php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enable "Access for less secure apps" :

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 0):

gmail does not allow to send emails from less secured applications. there is an option 'access for less secured apps' in google account settings. turn that on and you will be able to send emails.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing same issue some days before . i found this solution , may be it works for you.Pass your values like this. its strange but worked for me.

```
$username="googleaccount@gmail.com";
$password="pass":
$mail->Username = $username;
$mail->Password = $password;
```