# Google SMTP Error: Could not authenticate

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

The following code does not work once i put it on the server, I have similar code working on my local environment and it works perfectly, any ideas?

edit: i did set my gmail setting to "less secure"

```
<?php
$setid = $_POST['setid'];
$promo = $_POST['promo'];


echo "Good Sir, your set ID is ".$setid.", and you are eligible for the following deal:";
echo "<br><br>";
echo $promo;

$message=  "Good Sir, your set ID is ".$setid.", and you are eligible for the following deal:"."<br><br>".$promo;

    require "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";

    // Instantiate Class  
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    // Set up SMTP  
    $mail->IsSMTP();               
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;         
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; 
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
    $mail->Port = 465; 
    $mail->Encoding = '7bit';

    // Authentication  
    $mail->Username   = "xxx@example.com";
    $mail->Password   = "mypass";

    // Compose
    $mail->SetFrom("jghh@ghh.ca");
    $mail->AddReplyTo("ghh@ghh.ca");
    $mail->Subject = "TryIt";
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);

    // Send To  
    $mail->AddAddress("receiver@hotmail.com", "Recipient Name");
    $result = $mail->Send();
    $message = $result ? 'Successfully Sent!' : 'Sending Failed!';     

    unset($mail);



?>
```

This is what I get in Network -> Preview:

Good Sir, your set ID is 100065, and you are eligible for the following deal:

Current Promotion: Enjoy 15% discount on your next visit!SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Comment: I hope you didn't post you real password here... `$mail->Password   = "YOUR PASS"`

Comment: You're using a very old version of PHPMailer and you have not [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki).

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["SMTP Error: Could not authenticate" in PHPMailer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949824/smtp-error-could-not-authenticate-in-phpmailer)

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to enable [less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

---

> Change account access for less secure apps
>
> To help keep Google Apps users' accounts secure, we may block less
>   secure apps from accessing Google Apps accounts. As a Google Apps
>   user, you will see a "Password incorrect" error when trying to sign
>   in. If this is the case, you have two options:
>
> 1. Option 1: Upgrade to a more secure app that uses the most up to date
>      security measures. All Google products, like Gmail, use the latest
>      security measures.
> 2. Option 2: Change your settings to allow less secure apps to access
>      your account. We don't recommend this option because it might make
>      it easier for someone to break into your account. If you want to
>      allow access anyway, follow these steps:
>
>    2.1. Go to the "[Less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6009563)" section in My Account
>
>    2.2. Next to "Access for less secure apps," select Turn on. (Note to
>      Google Apps users: This setting is hidden if your administrator has locked less secure app account access.)
>
> If you still can't sign in to your account, the "[password
>   incorrect](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6009563)" error might be caused by a different reason.

SRC: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

---

**UPDATE:**

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

and enable debug on PHPMAILER

```
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1; // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                       // 1 = errors and messages
                       // 2 = messages only
```

to see if it yields anything.

Comment: actually i did, before it didnt even work on my local environment, after i made it less secure it worked on my local environment :)

Comment: i'd love to but it didnt solve my problem, because the problem im having is that the code gives me error when i put it on the server

Comment: I've updated my answer, you need to debug to understand what's wrong.