# Failed opening required 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a hosting server where i have written a php code which is giving me an error, i cant access php.ini as its a hosting server to change anythng

> Error :  Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/vhosts/evoting.freevar.com/vote/mailtest.php on line 2

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

        //Create a new PHPMailer instance
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
        $mail->isSMTP();
        //Enable SMTP debugging
        // 0 = off (for production use)
        // 1 = client messages
        // 2 = client and server messages
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
        $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
        //Set the hostname of the mail server
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
        $mail->Port = 587;
        //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        //Whether to use SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
        $mail->Username = "sample@gmail.com";
        //Password to use for SMTP authentication
        $mail->Password = "password";
        //Set who the message is to be sent from
        $mail->setFrom('sample@gmail.com', 'Evoting System');
        //Set an alternative reply-to address
        $mail->addReplyTo('sample@gmail.com', 'Evoting System');
        //Set who the message is to be sent to
        $mail->addAddress('azaz3@gmail.com', '');
        //Set the subject line
        $mail->Subject = 'EVoting Otp ';
        //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
        //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
        $mail->msgHTML('23bj34');
        //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
        $mail->AltBody = 'sddsfsd23';
        //Attach an image file
        // $mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif');

        // send the message, check for errors
        if (!$mail->send()) {
             echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
     echo "Message sent!";
        }

?>
```

I read related post on stackoverflow, but didnt had success yet. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["SMTP Error: Could not authenticate" in PHPMailer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949824/smtp-error-could-not-authenticate-in-phpmailer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check your current working directory, like this:

```
echo getcwd();
```

If you do so, you will see which is your active folder. The next thing you need to do is to check whether there is a `PHPMailer-master` folder inside your active folder (case-sensitive if you are using Linux). If it does not exist, then you will need to point to the right location instead or to create the folder and copy the file(s) into it. If it exists, check whether you have the necessary privileges and whether there is a file called `PHPMailerAutoload.php` inside that folder (again, case-sensitive if you are using Linux).

Comment: Thanks @Lajos Arpad
After getting cwd it worked for me. Another issue now is i am unable to send smtp mail from web hosting server, while its working for localhost.

Comment: @Ajazz, with pleasure. The other problem you encountered is a different question. You will need to look into the error logs on the server and to take a look at the mailer error you are echoing out as well.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't rocket science - the error message is very clear - you just need to use the correct path to the autoloader (and the rest of the PHPMailer files), wherever that is for your server. No need to edit php.ini.