# PHPMailer ERROR USING GMAIL: Mailer Error: SMTP connect()

Tags: php, xampp, gmail, phpmailer

I tried to send email from my localhost using my gmail account.
I also tried to find answers in the web and even in this website but nothing helped me. I am using XAMPP.

This is the code:

```
require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();         // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP();                 // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;            // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;          // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';       // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;               // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "myUser@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "myUserPass";
$mail->SetFrom("myUser@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("OtherUser@gmail.com");

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

The full error which I got:

> 2017-04-03 10:33:15   SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP
>   p7sm17594308wrc.19 - gsmtp 2017-04-03 10:33:15    CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO
>   localhost 2017-04-03 10:33:15 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at
>   your service, [46.117.89.127] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH
>   LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
>   250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8
>   2017-04-03 10:33:15   CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2017-04-03
>   10:33:15  SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 2017-04-03 10:33:15  CLIENT
>   -> SERVER: bXlVc2VyQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ== 2017-04-03 10:33:15   SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 2017-04-03 10:33:15  CLIENT -> SERVER:
>   bXlVc2VyUGFzcw== 2017-04-03 10:33:15  SERVER -> CLIENT: 535-5.7.8
>   Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8
>   https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials p7sm17594308wrc.19 -
>   gsmtp 2017-04-03 10:33:15 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed:
>   535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8
>   https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials p7sm17594308wrc.19 -
>   gsmtp 2017-04-03 10:33:15 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
>   2017-04-03 10:33:15   CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2017-04-03 10:33:16  SERVER
>   -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection p7sm17594308wrc.19 - gsmtp 2017-04-03 10:33:16    SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Mailer
>   Error: SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

I tried to delete that:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
```

Or changing the port to 25/587 but it did not help.
Does someone know how to fix that?

Comment: set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1` it will give the error no, which will help you to debug

Comment: No it won't. `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2` shows server side errors, which the OP already did.

Comment: Read the Google links and the troubleshooting guide that the error message links to. Also, search before posting - this has been asked many times before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["SMTP Error: Could not authenticate" in PHPMailer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949824/smtp-error-could-not-authenticate-in-phpmailer)

Comment: updated code and text formatting for readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your username and password entered is correct, you need to authorize the external application use of gmail.

Follow the next steps and authorize to make it:

1. First, go to your [Google Account Management page](https://myaccount.google.com/)
2. Under the [Connected apps & sites](https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps), click `Allow less secure apps: ON`

In case it does not work, if your gmail account has 2-step verification enabled, [use an auto-generated password](https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/two-step-verification/enroll-welcome).

**Update:**

Although turning `Allow less secure apps: ON` might solve your problem, it should be taken as a troubleshooting tip and not as the final solution.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This will "fix" the reported problem, but you do not need to disable secure apps to use PHPMailer with Gmail. Read the docs.

Comment: @Synchro just saying 'read the docs' does not help anyone in improving answers and the gmail docs DOES say to disable secure apps as a troubleshoot tip.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=1-636268261334269899-3579076150&rd=1#cantsignin

Comment: It does when the docs explicitly cover this exact situation, and they are linked directly from the error message itself that the OP posted. Clicking a link really isn't that hard... Disabling secure apps may be a *troubleshooting* step, but it's not a proper solution; it just lets you confirm where the problem is so you can fix it properly. It's like disabling TLS verification; useful tool, unsuitable for production.

Comment: Ok, you got a point. Updated my answer with a word of caution.

Answer (score 0):

you should turn off Email protected in your Anti Virut or Firewall