# With PHPmailer how to fix: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. SMTP Error: Could not authenticate

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

This post has evolved from an initial problem where I had copied in code that caused an error due to formatting. I am now struggling with a new error. The inital problem has changed to a redundant one. I will check other posts for a potential fix. I have been following along with a tutorial about how to send email using PHPmailer and SMTP. I am using Xampp localhost. I have installed PHPmailer using composer. I am receiving the error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. message could not be sentSMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Help would be appreciated.

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$m = new PHPMailer(true);


try{
$m->SMTPDebug = 2;
$m->isSMTP();
$m->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$m->SMTPAuth = true;


$m->Username = 'munsonatl';
$m->Password = ' ';

$m->SMTPSecure = 'SSL';
$m->Port = 465;

$m->setFrom('munsonatl@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
$m->addAddress('munsonatl@gmail.com', 'Matt Macy');
$m->addReplyto('reply@mattmacy.com', 'replyAdress');


$m->Subject = "Here is an Email";
$m->Body = "This is the body of the email";
$m->AltBody = "This is the body of an email";
$m->send();
echo "message has been sent";

} catch (Exception $e){
echo "message could not be sent", $m->ErrorInfo;
}
```

?>
[image]

Comment: Place your `require_once` line below the `use` lines

Comment: Then I get another error on require_once: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'require_once' (T_REQUIRE_ONCE)

Comment: I even try using parenthesis around require_once: require_once ('vendor/autoload.php');
and get error: syntax error, unexpected 'require_once' (T_REQUIRE_ONCE)

Comment: Did you use `composer` to install [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)?

Comment: Yes I used composer tp install PHPmailer.

Comment: Are you running an old PHP version?

Comment: No I am not just updated to 7.2.2 yesterday

Comment: Tired changing uses to phpmailer lowercase and still receive error

Comment: Make a file that contains nothing but the use and require statements, see if you still get the error. If you do, do you perhaps have a preloaded file in your PHP config that is interfering?

Comment: I made the file and it still gives me the error

Comment: I just installed complete new version of xampp yesterday. It was clean install. Did the very straight forward install through composer. I don't believe my file organization in composer is faulty but will double check

Comment: When I comment out the use statement require "vendor/autoload.php"  doesnt raise error. I didnt get the use statements from the tutorial. they were in the comments. something is wrong with them

Comment: I tired to make changes to the use statements but dont entirely grasp their operation. when commented out of the file you told me to make I receive no errors.

Comment: I comment out use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception and I now I have an error on the process: Invalid address: (From): root@localhost
bool(false)

Comment: What version of PHPMailer? What tutorial did you follow? If all fails, start a new project and follow the installation instructions on the PHPMailer github https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: I followed this its very good:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQ3TXOxj7cs&t=5s I downloaded from packagist everything should be fine. I commented out use... \Exception and now get: SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
The following From address failed: munsonatl@gmail.com

Comment: I have the suspession that I might be receiving an error because of what I commented out

Comment: I had to change the app access to allow less secure access: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949824/smtp-error-could-not-authenticate-in-phpmailer

Answer (score 1):

Either lose the parentheses or the space after the function name.

```
require_once ‘vendor/autoload.php’;
```

Or

```
require_once(‘vendor/autoload.php’);
```

Comment: Still receiving error with require_once: require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: I noticed the uses dont mention the src folder that contains those files. added it and have this: use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\src\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\src\Exception;

Comment: That’s wrong. `use` statements are not file paths; they are name aliases.

Comment: I still get the error with: use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;